# What combos are available in Batman: Arkham City Lockdown?

Tags: batman-arkham-city-lockdown

**What combat combos are available in *Batman: Arkham City Lockdown*?**  The tutorial teaches you two:

- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd>
- <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd>

It then urges me to discover others.  To this point, I haven't found any.  My usual tactics are to wait for an enemy to attack, swipe <kbd>↓</kbd> to deflect, then use the <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> combo.

**What other combos are there?  What are the most powerful?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other combo attacks include:

- Left, Right, Down - Leg Kick
- Left, Right, Up - Right Uppercut
- Right, Left, Down - Gut Punch
- Right, Left, Up - Left Uppercut
- Right, Left, Right, Down - Side Kick
- Left, Right, Left, Up - Rising Uppercut (actually looks somewhat like the Dragon Punch from Street Fighter)

As for the power level of the combos, I haven't noticed much of a difference at this time, but then again a lot of my combos seem to be produced by blind luck rather than expert timing.